# how to update a var in did move to view ,outside of the did move to view in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm trying to update a sprite inside the "override func didMove(to view: SKView) {" at a random time every time it changes but it always stays at a constant time.

```
var randomTime = 1.9
let spritestater = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spritea1.png")
let sprite1 = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed:"spritea1.png"))
let sprite2 = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "sprite1b.png"))

 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    spritestater.scale(to: self.frame.size)
    spritestater.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    spritestater.zPosition = 1
    spritestater.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX, y: self.frame.maxY)
    addChild(spritestater)

    let anamatesprite = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence(
        [sprite1,
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomTime)),
        sprite2,
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.3),
        ]))
    spritestater.run(anamatesprite)
 }

 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    randomTime = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4.5)))
 }
```

Comment: @Farini while I agree that the question could use some editing, randomTime is not a constant. OP has setup it up properly inside the class declaration (assumption) and using var vs let.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your action is already running, changing the value of randomTime is not going to affect an action that is already running. also didMove(to view:) is only going to be called when the page is initially loaded, so that action inside there will never be run again.

What I am showing you is a horrible way of running this, but it'll show you that the randomTime will change and run the action at the new time

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    spritestater.scale(to: self.frame.size)
    spritestater.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    spritestater.zPosition = 1
    spritestater.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX, y: self.frame.maxY)
    addChild(spritestater)

    runActionOnSprite()
}

func runActionOnSprite() {
    let anamatesprite = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence(
    [sprite1,
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomTime)),
    sprite2,
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.3),
    ]))
    spritestater.run(anamatesprite)
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if !spritestater.hasActions()
        randomTime = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4.5)))
    }
}
```